# how to show ads and then restart scene after clicking restart button in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I am new to unity and I want one help, the below script is my Ad manager script.

I have one restart button and on click event, I want to show an ad and then start a scene, but when I click the restart button it shows an ad for few millisec and the scene starts...

How to show to fully and then load scene? Thank you.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ADSmanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InterstitialAd interstitial_Ad;
    private RewardedAd rewardedAd;

    private string interstitial_Ad_ID;
    private string rewardedAd_ID;

    void Start () {
        interstitial_Ad_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        rewardedAd_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";

        MobileAds.Initialize (initStatus => { });

        RequestInterstitial ();
        RequestRewardedVideo ();

    }

    private void RequestInterstitial () {
        interstitial_Ad = new InterstitialAd (interstitial_Ad_ID);
        interstitial_Ad.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
        interstitial_Ad.LoadAd (request);
    }

    private void RequestRewardedVideo () {
        rewardedAd = new RewardedAd (rewardedAd_ID);
        rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;
        rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardedAdClosed;
        rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow;
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
        rewardedAd.LoadAd (request);
    }

    public void ShowInterstitial () {
        if (interstitial_Ad.IsLoaded ()) {
            interstitial_Ad.Show ();
            RequestInterstitial ();
        }
        // else{
        //      Savers.Score=0;
        // Savers.died=false;
        // SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        // Time.timeScale=1;
        // }
       
        //Time.timeScale=1;
       
    }

    public void ShowRewardedVideo () {
        if (rewardedAd.IsLoaded ()) {
            rewardedAd.Show ();
            
        }

        
    }

    public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
 
        
    
}

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded (object sender, EventArgs args) {

       

    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow (object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args) {
        RequestRewardedVideo ();
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdClosed (object sender, EventArgs args) {
        RequestRewardedVideo ();
    }

    public void HandleUserEarnedReward (object sender, Reward args) {
        RequestRewardedVideo ();
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Load the scene inside this method. And in Editor, the close button will handle this method. As in the editor, no actual ads will be shown.

```
public void HandleUserEarnedReward (object sender, Reward args) {
    RequestRewardedVideo ();
    sceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
}
```

Comment: and for interstitial??

Comment: for interstitial,     `public void ShowInterstitial () {
        if (interstitial_Ad.IsLoaded ()) {
            interstitial_Ad.Show ();
            RequestInterstitial ();sceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
        }`

Comment: when I call this as you suggested .it shows ad and move to next scene automatically without closing the ad

Comment: Yes. That is what will happen in the editor. It will work fine in the android build.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Please, upvote the answer. So others don't have to add another solution for this.